# How I can build multilevelpie graph without padding in FusionCharts JS?

Tags: javascript, frontend, fusioncharts

I build FusionCharts multilevelpie graph. But huge indents appear.

500 x 500
With a decrease in space, the graph is greatly reduced.
[padding 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chTLt.png)

100% x 100%
When doing a full size chart, the indents become too large.
[padding 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgtpr.png)

When I reduce the space of the graph, the graph becomes too small.

My code:

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'multilevelpie',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',

    width: '500',
    height: '500',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "",
            "subcaption": "",
            "showPlotBorder": "1",
            "piefillalpha": "60",
            "pieborderthickness": "2",
            "hoverfillcolor": "#CCCCCC",
            "piebordercolor": "#FFFFFF",
            "hoverfillcolor": "#CCCCCC",
            "numberprefix": "#",
            "plottooltext": "$label",
            "theme": "fusion",
        },
        "category": {{ pie }},
    }
}
);
    fusioncharts.render();
    });
```

Comment: Don't work: 

"xAxisNamePadding": "0",
"yAxisNamePadding": "0",
"chartLeftMargin": "0",
"chartTopMargin": "0",
"chartRightMargin": "0",
"chartBottomMargin": "0",
"canvasPadding": "0",
 "valuePadding": "0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the outer part of the pie using pieRadius attribute at the chart object level, take a look at this sample -

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var topProductsChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'multilevelpie',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    id: "myChart",
    width: '400',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Split of Top Products Sold",
        "subCaption": "Last Quarter",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
        "baseFontColor": "#333333",
        "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
        "basefontsize": "9",
        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "showShadow": "0",
        "showCanvasBorder": "0",
        "pieFillAlpha": "60",
        "pieBorderThickness": "2",
        "hoverFillColor": "#cccccc",
        "pieBorderColor": "#ffffff",
        "useHoverColor": "1",
        "showValuesInTooltip": "1",
        "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "plotTooltext": "$label, $$valueK, $percentValue",
        "pieRadius": "170"
      },
      "category": [{
        "label": "Sales by category",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "value": "150",
        "category": [{
            "label": "Food & {br}Beverages",
            "color": "#f8bd19",
            "value": "55.5",
            "category": [{
                "label": "Breads",
                "color": "#f8bd19",
                "value": "11.1"
              },
              {
                "label": "Juice",
                "color": "#f8bd19",
                "value": "27.75"
              },
              {
                "label": "Noodles",
                "color": "#f8bd19",
                "value": "9.99"
              },
              {
                "label": "Seafood",
                "color": "#f8bd19",
                "value": "6.66"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "Apparel &{br}Accessories",
            "color": "#e44a00",
            "value": "42",
            "category": [{
                "label": "Sun Glasses",
                "color": "#e44a00",
                "value": "10.08"
              },
              {
                "label": "Clothing",
                "color": "#e44a00",
                "value": "18.9"
              },
              {
                "label": "Handbags",
                "color": "#e44a00",
                "value": "6.3"
              },
              {
                "label": "Shoes",
                "color": "#e44a00",
                "value": "6.72"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "Baby {br}Products",
            "color": "#008ee4",
            "value": "22.5",
            "category": [{
                "label": "Bath &{br}Grooming",
                "color": "#008ee4",
                "value": "9.45"
              },
              {
                "label": "Feeding",
                "color": "#008ee4",
                "value": "6.3"
              },
              {
                "label": "Diapers",
                "color": "#008ee4",
                "value": "6.75"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "Electronics",
            "color": "#33bdda",
            "value": "30",
            "category": [{
                "label": "Laptops",
                "color": "#33bdda",
                "value": "8.1"
              },
              {
                "label": "Televisions",
                "color": "#33bdda",
                "value": "10.5"
              },
              {
                "label": "SmartPhones",
                "color": "#33bdda",
                "value": "11.4"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  });

  topProductsChart.render();
});
```

Here is a live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cebu68vt/

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to explicitly set the outer radius of the pie chart. Specify the outer radius of the pie/doughnut chart using pieRadius attribute.

```
 "pieRadius": "50",
```

To know more about this feature please check here - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#customize-pie-radius

Check the demo here - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/rds15mvs/